# Ecommerce web dev framework? Shopify APIs?

Tags: reactjs, shopify, e-commerce, shopify-hydrogen

I'm trying to develop an ecommerce website and am thinking about using Shopify's hydrogen framework.

Can I use hydrogen on the frontend and shopify as my backend for free? I plan to host this myself and just want to know if my hydrogen web app will be able to access my shopify store through the APIs after the 14 day free trial.

Essentially, I just want to build an ecommerce website without being tied into a paid plan. If you know an alternative to hydrogen or an open source way to handle shopping carts, payment, etc...I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pay for Shopify. You cannot transact payments without paying for a Shopify subscription. If you want to make your own front-end for the shopping experience, that is up to you. Hydrogen is one example of doing that. But it does not free you from having to pay for Shopify to manage your products that you sell, or the orders you generate. No code of your own frees you up from that.